# How can I access one class variable from another class?

Tags: java

There are two separate classes `class A` and `class B`. Both classes are in the same package. I want to access data of one class from the other class. How can I access variable data of a class?. My program is very lengthy, I just want the logic of this.

***Class A.java***

```
public class A
{ 
  public static void main(String ar[])  
  {
    int a=100;
  }  
}
```

***Class B.java***

```
public class B extends A
{
  public static void main(String m[])
  {
     A obj=new A();
     System.out.println("Variable of class A is :"+ obj.a);
  }
}
```

I have done this thing to get access like I declared a variable `a` as Static so that I can directly get access but it's not working. And when I am compiling ***B.java*** it is giving me error

> cannot find symbol at := System.out.println("Variable of class A is :"+ **obj.a**);

And

> Illegal start of expression

(**when I am declaring variable a as public**)

:-(error)public int a=100; [in class A].

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using the static main method? Besides that the field `a` is local and not accessible outside the scope. Use this instead.

```
public class A
{ 
  public int a;
  public A()  
   {
    a=100;
   }  
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just answering something similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have two true object-oriented classes above, but rather little more than two receptacles for static main methods. To combine code from two classes well, you will want to scrap that code and make OOP-compliant classes, complete with instance fields and methods. For more on this, check out the OOP section of the Java tutorials: [link to OOP tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Comment: Huh? What kind of answer is this? You can answer with the community wiki?

Comment: @MuratK.: the question really is: "I don't know anything about Java OOP", and is a very weak question IMO. The best answer is to refer him to a tutorial to learn OOP. He doesn't really need specific code on how to do what he wants, he needs to learn broad concepts, concepts too broad to be able to include in any decent answer here. Since the quality of the answer and question are both somewhat poor, I made it a community wiki so I wouldn't get credit for any up-votes or down-votes.

Comment: Okay, never saw a community wiki answer. Thought they are some ancient relics or so.

Comment: so instead of giving me link can u directly give me answer. And i am good at OOP,,asking This question does not mean that i don't know about OOP

Comment: @MuratK.: for more on Community Wiki, please see: [Community Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) and [meta-Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: @kush: sorry, I call it as I see it. Your question shows that if you think you are good at OOP, you're quite wrong.

Comment: Hey dude i dont want to learn oop concept i know it ,,its just a query i came across. This question doesnot mean that i dont know OOP.

Comment: @kush: I'm not going to argue with you, but if you were so expert at OOP, or even a rank beginner in it, you'd know that that was the solution to your question.

Answer (score 3):

First, get rid of `main()` in `A`.  You only want *one* `main()` in your application, and it's in `B` (since the one in `A` doesn't actually *do* anything):

```
public class A {
}
```

Now, you want `A` to have a class-level `int` value:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
}
```

And you want it to have a default value of `100`, yes?  A constructor is a good place to do that:

```
public class A {
    private int a;

    public A() {
        this.a = 100;
    }
}
```

*Now* any time you do this:

```
A obj = new A();
```

you will have an object with a value.  In order to *access* that value from outside that object, you need a "getter":

```
public class A {
    private int a;

    public A() {
        this.a = 100;
    }

    public int get_a() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

*Now* in `B` (or anywhere, really), you can create an instance of `A` and access that value by using the "getter":

```
A obj=new A();
System.out.println("Variable of class A is :"+ obj.get_a());
```

---

Semantically, don't think of it as "accessing a variable from another class".  Instead, think of what your *objects* are and what they represent.  If it were a physical, real-world object which internally contained some kind of value.

When you create an instance of that object, the instance would internally have that value somewhere.  From the *outside* of that object, it doesn't really *matter* how that value is internally maintained.  There just needs to be some kind of interface to see the value.  Which is what the "getter" method does.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner answer: To access a variable outside a class, make it class-level. You have written a method-level variable that's accessible only inside that scope (method).

To elaborate:

> There are to separate classes class One and class Two. Both of classes are in same package. I want to access one class data into other class how can i access variable data.

So basically you know that to by extending, you should be able to access parent class data into your subclass. For that, simply make the data in your parent class as class level.

```
class A {
    int var = 10; //class level, but non-static, so to access you need A object

    void method() {
        int var = 20; //this is method local and can not be accessed outside
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aObj = new A();
        System.out.println(aObj.var);
    }
}
```

> Illegal start of expression (when i am delaring variable a as public)

Its illegal. Because access modifiers like `public`, `private` etc. are applicable to class-level stuff like the first `var` or the `main` method in `class B` you see.

**Said that:**
You need to immediately go here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
rather than just trying to run some classes when you lack language basics.